# Why am I getting a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT here?

Tags: opengl

I have the following code. I'm trying to create a Multisample Framebuffer that has two color attachments and a depth-stencil attachment.

```
/* Generate Framebuffer and textures & renderbuffers */
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboColorAttachment);
glGenTextures(1, &m_fboAdditionalInfo);

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_fboRenderbufferDepthStencil);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);

    /* setup color output 0 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, m_fboColorAttachment);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGBA8, renderDimensionsX, renderDimensionsY, GL_FALSE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, m_fboColorAttachment, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);

    /* setup color output 1 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, m_fboAdditionalInfo);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_R32UI, renderDimensionsX, renderDimensionsY, GL_FALSE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, m_fboAdditionalInfo, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);

    /* setup depth and stencil */
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_fboRenderbufferDepthStencil);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, renderDimensionsX, renderDimensionsY);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_fboRenderbufferDepthStencil);

    auto status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::wstring statusStr = L"WTF error";
        if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
            statusStr = L"Attachment";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT)
            statusStr = L"Missing attachment";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER)
            statusStr = L"Draw buffer";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER)
            statusStr = L"Read buffer";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED)
            statusStr = L"Unsupported";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED)
            statusStr = L"Undefined";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE)
            statusStr = L"Multisample";
        else if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS)
            statusStr = L"Layer targets";
        drawFuncLog << L"Framebuffer status: " << statusStr << L"\r\n";
    }

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I'm getting the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` status returned. As near as I can tell, everything has been created as multisampled and the number of multisample levels matches across the attachments. Incomplete Attachment apparently means one of my attachments is incomplete, which I think is the depth-stencil renderbuffer.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of [`glRenderbufferStorageMultisample`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorageMultisample.xhtml) has to be the internal format of the buffer, but not `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`.

Comment: MY bad, it's now `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` but the error remains.

Comment: But the new error is `FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE`. See the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 9.4.2 Whole Framebuffer Completeness; page 326](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> The framebuffer object bound to target is said to be framebuffer complete if all the following conditions are true:
>   ......
>
> - The value of `TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS` is the same for all attached textures; and, if the attached images are a **mix of renderbuffers and textures**, the value of `TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS` must be **`TRUE`** for all attached textures.

This means you have to pass `GL_TRUE`, to the last parameter of [`glTexImage2DMultisample`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2DMultisample.xhtml) for both texture attachments, to solve the issue:

```
glTexImage2DMultisample(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_RGBA8, renderDimensionsX, renderDimensionsY, GL_TRUE);
```

```
glTexImage2DMultisample(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 4, GL_R32UI, renderDimensionsX, renderDimensionsY, GL_TRUE);
```